# Strange behaviour when inheriting from a list in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I was fiddling around with inheritance recently and I'm a little confused by the behaviour of the following:

```
class Foo(list):

    def method(self, thing):
        new = self + [thing]
        print(new)
        self = new
        print(self)

    def method2(self, thing):
        self += [thing]

>>> f = Foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> f.method(10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
>>> f
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> f.method2(10)
>>> f
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
```

Why does the in-place method `method2` work but the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how in-place operators work.

`self = self + [thing]` creates a new list and put it into the local variable `self`, overriding the passed one. But it doesn't modify the object itself. Internally, it does `self = self.__add__([thing])`.

`self += [thing]`, OTOH, modifies the list in-place. Internally it tries `self = self.__iadd__([thing])` first. `iadd` stands for "inplace add". Only if that doesn't exist, `self = self.__add__([thing])` is called.

The difference is that `__add__()` always creates a new object and leaves the others untouched. `__iadd__()`, however, is supposed to try first to *modify* the object it operates on. In this case, it returns it so that no *change* of object occurs, i. e. `self` refers to the same object as before. Only if this is not possible, it returns a new one which is then assigned.

Answer (score 0):

`list.__add__()` (the `+` operator builtin) creates a new list, while `list.__iadd__()` (the `+=` operator builtin) modifies the list in place.