# Is there a better way to write this code to alter an object inheriting from `list` in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

In response to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838848/strange-behaviour-when-inheriting-from-a-list-in-python) I had, I am now wondering it there is any way of making the following code look nicer:

```
class Cycle(list):

    def insertextend(self, index, other, reverse = False):
        """Extend the cycle by inserting an iterable at the given position."""
        index %= len(self)
        if reverse:
            super(Cycle, self).__init__(self[:index] + list(reversed(other)) + self[index:])
        else:
            super(Cycle, self).__init__(self[:index] + other + self[index:])
```

Any ideas as to how I can remove the `super(Cycle, self).__init__(...)`?

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid using `super`? What exactly are you hoping to gain here?

Comment: That just feels kind of hack-ish to me to call list's `__init__` every time I want to alter the data in Cycle. I was just wondering if I'm doing it right or not.

Comment: What's the purpose of the following? `index %= len(self)`

Comment: The Cycle object I was fiddling around with is basically a list that never raises an index error. An index greater than the length of the list gets rolled back.

Comment: `self[index:index] = other`?  I don't really understand what your class is doing (that a list doesn't already), but that matches the semantics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I didn't notice that this wasn't in the `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def insertextend(self, index, other, reverse = False):
            """Extend the cycle by inserting an iterable at the given position."""
            index %= len(self)
            if reverse: other = reversed(other)
            self[index:index] = other
```